# Hudson or Jenkins Parameterized Builds using dynamic choices

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins

Is there a plugin or ability to write some type of JSP or script to allow a Hudson or Jenkins [parametrized build](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build) to generate the dropdown choices dynamically.

For example if we have a single parametrized build that operates on one of the workspaces being managed in Hudson (where we'd rather not create a job per workspace). We "create" new workspaces daily and we'd like the parametrized build to be able to display those workspaces in a dropdown box as a parameter to that job.

It'd be nice if I could just embed a JSP script or something that would be executed to return a list of choices.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something similar. A plugin that could take an SQL connection would be nice. Trying to populate our environments from puppet stored config database would be useful to us. I may take a stab at developing a simple plugin myself. I'll post if I get something working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exact behavior you are looking for doesn't exist yet as far as I'm aware, but the [Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) comes close.

If that doesn't work, it would also not be a very complicated plugin to write. If you want to take a stab at writing it yourself, you can take a look at [this introduction to the plugin environment](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) and [this more comprehensive overview of plugin development](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins) (there's much more information there than you'd actually need; you might want to just extend the Extended Choice Parameter instead, since it already has the infrastructure set up).

If you don't want to do it yourself, you could create a feature request in [Jenkins' issue tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org) (assuming you don't find another feature request that would also satisfy your needs; I didn't see one, but I don't know much about your environment), and somebody else might pick it up.

In the meantime, I think you could use the Extended Choice Parameter, combined with a script that automatically wrote to a file whenever anybody created a new workspace.

Comment: The Extended Choice Parameter Plugin I think will work for us. The key feature is being able to point it to a properties file that we'll update when we add a new directory that we want to add to the choice list.