# Jenkins Parameterized choice

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I want to create a job with two parameters. The first one gives a choice of environments (like DEV, TEST, PROD). Once the environment is selected I want the second parameter to show the list of servers from the selected environment. So the user can select ALL or a particular server to install. Is it possible to do this in Jenkins or any of its plugins? Basically I want the second choice box to be updated when the first choice box is selected.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the default parameterized build option in Jenkins.  There may be another plugin written that does this (there are many many community contributed plugins) but I'm not aware of one.

However I have written several custom Jenkins plugins to essentially customize the build page UI for needs that are specific to my company.  Writing a Jenkins plugin seems intimidating at first, but it actually isn't too hard if you know Java and Maven.  If you don't know either of those, then you will need to find someone who does.  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

Here is a similar question with a similar answer: [Hudson or Jenkins Parameterized Builds using dynamic choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398031/hudson-or-jenkins-parameterized-builds-using-dynamic-choices)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that much dynamic choice parameters are available through plugins also. But you can try out this plugin to get what you want. [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) to achieve what you want. But not exactly you want. Hope this helps.